# Right way to cross-reference a theorem-like object in section header, with amsbook class

Tags: cross-referencing, amsbook

I am having some trouble with referencing theorems in section titles. Say, I want to have a section with

```
\section{Proof of Lemma~\ref{l:main}}
```

The ToC looks fine and it displays correctly where the title is placed. However, on the top of each page in the section, I would have something like "Proof of Lemma ??". Please see the picture below.

I wonder if there's a fix to this? I'm using the `amsbook` document class with all the standard packages.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the problem arises because the `amsbook` class renders material in header lines in uppercase. This means that "Proof of Lemma~\ref{l:main}" gets processed as "PROOF OF LEMMA~\ref{L:MAIN}", which generates an "undefined reference" warning message since you've probably run `\begin{lemma} \label{l:main} ... \end{lemma}`. The remedy? Change `\label{l:main}` to `\label{L:MAIN}`, and `\ref{l:main}` to `\ref{L:MAIN}`. Somewhat ugly, but it works...

Comment: Aha! You're right Mico. Capitalizing the label solves the problem! Thank you very much! It's a bit unfortunate however, like you said...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because soilved in comments by Mico.

Comment: Shouldn't we let @Mico turn his comment into an answer? It is a good one

Comment: @EladDen - Thanks, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm re-posting my earlier comment on @EladDen's encouragement as an answer. I suspect this topic has come up before, but I couldn't find a perfect antecedent that would make the query into a duplicate.)

The problem you've encountered arises because the `amsbook` class renders material in header lines in uppercase. This means that

```
Proof of Lemma~\ref{l:main}
```

gets processed as

```
PROOF OF LEMMA~\ref{L:MAIN}
```

This, in turn, generates an "undefined reference" warning message, since you've probably run `\begin{lemma} \label{l:main} ... \end{lemma}`.

The remedy? Change `\label{l:main}` to `\label{L:MAIN}` and `\ref{l:main}` to `\ref{L:MAIN}`. Somewhat ugly, but it works...